# Selection sort issues

Tags: java, selection-sort

Feel as if im so close, just dont know what to put in "If Statment" and order of things. Please Help. Also not sure what to do with swap method for sure?

```
private static void selectionSort(String[] words, int numWords)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)  
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++)
        {
            if(words[index]<words[minIndex])
            {
                min = j;
            }

        swap(words, i, j);
        }
    } 
}

public static int indexOfNextSmallest(String[] words, int startIndex) 
{
    int minIndex = startIndex;

    for(int i = startIndex; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(words[i].compareTo(words[minIndex]) < 0)
            minIndex = i;
    }
    return minIndex;
}

private static void swap(String[] words, int i, int j)
{
    String swap = words[i];
    words[i] = words[j];
    words[j] = swap;
}
```

Trying to add user validation. Wondering if I should do it in method below or up in main method?

```
private static int getMenuChoice(Scanner stdIn)
{
    int option = 0;

    System.out.println("\n1:  Add Word");
    System.out.println("2:  Remove Word");
    System.out.println("3:  Print Words");
    System.out.println("4:  Quit");
    System.out.print("Choose an option(1-4): ");
    option = stdIn.nextInt();

    return option;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare 2 strings using **'<'** operator which doesnt work. Rather you should use compareTo function to compare 2 objects that are **Comparable**.

```
   if(words[index]<words[minIndex])   // doesnt work - Compilation error
   {
            min = j;
   }
```

Change your if condition in the method selectionSort as follows :

```
    if(words[j].comapareTo(words[min]) < 0)
    {
            min = j;
    }
```

Also you need to swap words at index i & min, rather than swapping i & j

```
  swap(words, i, j);  //wrong

  swap(words, i, min); //correct -  as it swaps min word & current word
```

Comment: alright makes sense, other question. I added int minIndex to selectionSort heading, what do I use instead of index?

Comment: private static void selectionSort(String[] words, int numWords, int minIndex)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)  
      {
       int min = i;
       for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++)
       {
        if(words[index].compareTo(words[minIndex]) < 0)
        {
         min = j;
        }
       
       swap(words, i, j);
       }
      } 
    }

Comment: Use j instead of index. Also swap i and min

Comment: works great. thanks alot. just added another method to example. wonder if I add user validation there or in main method?

Comment: depends on what you are validating and the need

Comment: well for that method/area i need to validate they are entering 1-4 and not a letter. Other area i need to validate they are entering a word not a number.

Comment: Validation should be done when user inputs the data, rather than when you want to sort the data

Comment: so far method shown I should add a while loop in the method?